# Is it possible to open and watch RatDVD Files on a Mac?

Tags: video, dvd

Is it possible to watch movies in the format of RatDVD on a mac? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RatDVD is a proprietary format created by the program itself. The developer has no plans to make a Mac app, so if VLC wont play it you will either have to watch the files through a windows virtual machine or watch them through a windows partition.